# Cross promoting apps for iPhone apps

Tags: ios, xcode

I was wondering if it is allowed by Apple to cross promote your apps within your app. I was thinking of having a pop-up window appear asking the user if they would like to download another game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is allowed. I remember a couple of games (Icomania comes to mind) where, in the free version, they show an advertisement of one of their other games once every 3 or 4 questions.

Answer (score 0):

yes its allowed, i did that many times with no problem

Check this free version for your cross promotion library
its open source library

https://github.com/mfa01/CrossAdsWithFirebase